# Displaying corresponding text relating to check box names in Word 2010 and visual Studio 2010 that is removed when box is unchecked?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, templates, ms-word

The code im currently using in Visual Studio to populate a text field when check boxes are clicked on is:

```
    private void checkBox1_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        this.displayText.Text += "Internal Use";
    }

    private void checkBox2_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        this.displayText.Text += "Company Confidential";
    }

    private void checkBox3_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        this.displayText.Text += "Customer Confidential";
    }

    private void checkBox4_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        this.displayText.Text += "Strictly Confidential";
    }
```

This is fine but i'd like the text to be removed when the boxes are not checked. Does anybody have any insight into the specific code that I might need to make this requirement functional?

Many thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you mean something like

```
private void checkBox1_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (checkBox1.Checked)
        this.displayText.Text = "Internal Use";
    else
        this.displayText.Text = String.Empty;
}
```

And are you sure this isn't C# you're talking about?

Comment: That's absolutely perfect thank you. Apologies it was c# that I was speaking of, very new concept to me and I got a little bit muddled. Many thanks!